# Mixinig async context manager and straight await in asyncio

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.5

How to mix

```
async with api.open() as o:
    ...
```

and

```
o = await api.open()
```

in one function?

Since first require object with `__aenter__` and `__aexit__`, but second require `__await__`, which should be generator without `await`.

My attempt was:

```
def AsyncContext(aenter, aexit):

    class AsyncContextClass:

        async def __aenter__(self):

            return await aenter()

        async def __aexit__(self, *args):

            return await aexit(*args)

        def __await__(self):

            return (yield from aenter())

    return AsyncContextClass()
```

But it fails with `__await__` if `aenter` defined with `async def` (`TypeError: cannot 'yield from' a coroutine object in a non-coroutine generator`).

It works fine with `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator for `aenter`, but this is «dirty».

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can return `__aenter__`'s `__await__` from your class's `__await__`:

```
# vim: tabstop=4 expandtab

import asyncio

class Test(object):

    async def __aenter__(self):
        print("enter")

    async def __aexit__(self, *args):
        print("exit")

    def __await__(self):
        return self.__aenter__().__await__()

async def run():
    async with Test():
        print("hello")

    await Test()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
loop.close()
```

Output:

```
enter
hello
exit
enter
```

Comment: Why `return self.__aenter__().__await__()`? Shouldn't it be `return self.__aenter__()`?

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.8.5 you can do something like this

```py
from httpx import AsyncClient
from asyncio import run


async def main():
    api_base_url = 'https://google.com/'

    api_session_build = AsyncClient(base_url=api_base_url)

    # Enter Async Context manager

    apisession = await api_session_build.__aenter__()

    # Do stuff

    print( await apisession.get('/photos/about/'))

    # Exit Async Context Manager

    await apisession.__aexit__()

run(main())
```

Comment: This was possible before 3.8.5.